# How to store values from "String: Any Object" to an empty String Array

Tags: swift

I receive the following warning:

> "Cannot assign value of type '[String : AnyObject]' to type 'String' "

for the following line:

```
TrueData[counter] = newRow
```

`TrueData` is initialized as:

```
var TrueData = [String]()
```

and `newRow` is initialized as:

```
var newRow = [String:AnyObject]()
```

`newRow` must be `AnyObject` so how can I store its values inside a string array after each iteration of a for loop (the code is sorting through a CSV file)?

Here is the entire block of code as suggested in the comments:

```
func convertCSV(stringData:String) -> [[String:AnyObject]] {
    //for date formatting
    var  importDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = importDateFormat
    var TrueData = [String]()
    //dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")

    let rows = cleanRows(stringData: stringData)
    if rows.count > 0 {
        //data = []
        //var TrueData = [String: Any]()
        var  columnTitles:[String] = []
        var  columnType:[String] = ["NSDate","Int","Int"]
        var counter = 0


        columnTitles = cleanFields(oldString: rows.first!)
        for row in rows{
            let fields = cleanFields(oldString: row)
            if fields.count != columnTitles.count {continue}
            var newRow = [String:AnyObject]()
            for index in 1..<fields.count{ let column = columnTitles[index]; 
let field = fields[index]; switch columnType[index]
            { case "Int": newRow[column] = Int(field) as AnyObject case 
"NSDate": guard let newField = dateFormatter.date(from: field)
                else { print ("\(field) didn\'t convert");
                    continue };
            newRow[column] = newField as AnyObject default: //default keeps as 
string
                newRow[column] = field as AnyObject } };


            TrueData[counter] = newRow
            counter = counter + 1
        } }

    else { print("No data in file") };
    return TrueData };
```

Comment: You are trying to assign a `Dictionary` to a `String` variable. How do you want that to look? Show more relevant code with your loop and related variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep trueData as an array of rows, then you might nee to use like below

```
var TrueData = [[String:AnyObject]]()

var newRow = [String:AnyObject]()

TrueData.append(newRow)
```

But if you want to use the TrueData as a dictionary, then like below,

```
let counter = "key"

var TrueData = [String: String]()

var newRow = [String:AnyObject]()

TrueData[counter] = newRow
```

[updated]

I replaced in two places, one declaration area and the adding to the array place. Just try to use this.

```
func convertCSV(stringData:String) -> [[String:AnyObject]] {
        //for date formatting
        var  importDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = importDateFormat

        /* ------- REPLACED: var TrueData = [String]() ------------- */
        var TrueData = [[String:AnyObject]]() /* */
        /* --------------------- REPLACED --------------------------- */

        //dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")

        let rows = cleanRows(stringData: stringData)
        if rows.count > 0 {
            //data = []
            //var TrueData = [String: Any]()
            var  columnTitles:[String] = []
            var  columnType:[String] = ["NSDate","Int","Int"]
            var counter = 0


            columnTitles = cleanFields(oldString: rows.first!)
            for row in rows{
                let fields = cleanFields(oldString: row)
                if fields.count != columnTitles.count {continue}
                var newRow = [String:AnyObject]()
                for index in 1..<fields.count{ let column = columnTitles[index];
                    let field = fields[index]; switch columnType[index]
                    { case "Int": newRow[column] = Int(field) as AnyObject case
                    "NSDate": guard let newField = dateFormatter.date(from: field)
                        else { print ("\(field) didn\'t convert");
                            continue };
                    newRow[column] = newField as AnyObject default: //default keeps as string
                        newRow[column] = field as AnyObject } };


                /* ----------- REPLACED: TrueData[counter] = newRow ---------------- */
                TrueData.append(newRow) /* */
                /* --------------------- REPLACED --------------------------- */
                counter = counter + 1
            } }

        else { print("No data in file") };
        return TrueData
    };
```

Comment: When I attempt the first correction I get an error telling me  "Cannot convert return expression of type '[[String : AnyObject]]' to return type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>'" and even changing the function return type to "Dictionart<String, AnyObject>" does not remove this error. I could show more of my code but I do not believe it is relevant and it may only make matters more confusing

Comment: can you add the complete function with the return type? I am guessing you are returning TrueData, but it is expecting a different type.